# How to I use `select` in elixir?

Tags: elixir

Ruby has `select` and `reject` - How do I return all elements where a given function returns `true` for an enumerable in Elixir? What is the keyword?

Answer (score 5):

In Elixir, the corresponding function for `select` is `filter/2`.

So use `filter/2` instead of `select`,
and `reject/2` just the same as in ruby.

For the official documentation, see:

`filter/2`: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2

`reject/2`: (opposite of filter):
https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reject/2

Comment: To save others' time - `reduce` is not the opposite of filter, as of Elixir 1.5.1 - it's a completely different function, don't confuse the two! Use `reject` instead.

Comment: Did the OP mean to say `reject/2` and write reduce instead?